Activating Windows user in Jenkins pipeline
In my pipeline, I run a Windows Azure VM and create an additional user on it that will be used later to connect to the machine through the RDP protocol.
This user is created with it's password, but is not activated, his home folder isn't created either. I need this folder to put there a _netrc file for the user.
If I create a folder manually where it should be and put the _netrc file there, after the connection through RDP another folder is created with the name of \username.machine_name and all the settings and user's folders are there instead of the one created by me
If I create a folder with this name myself, then another folder is created with the name \username and all the settings go there, again instead of the one I created
ChatGPT advised to activate the user by running a command that starts a terminal as the new user and then closes it, but it didn't help. Anyone knows how to actually activate a new user via script in Jenkins?
